# How to treat a word and a Font Awesome icon as one when wrapping?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a navigation that has a Font Awesome arrow at the end, and when the page narrows down, the wrap makes the arrow appear on the line below (as shown in the Codepen).

I would like it so the last word and the arrow are treated as one object, so if there is not enough room for the arrow in the width, then the last word will jump down with the arrow?

How would you approach this?

Thanks!

http://codepen.io/b-d-m-p/pen/dPPzod?editors=110

```
<div class="box">
  <ul>    
    <li>
      <a>This way<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the css:

```
.box{
  width: 110px;
  border: dashed gray 1px;
    a{
        color: gray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<a>This <span style="white-space: nowrap">way<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
```

This will make the icon AND the word wrap onto the next line, but not the word "this".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Just apply `white-space:nowrap;`

```
.box{
  width: 110px;
  border: dashed gray 1px;
    a{
        color: gray;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
}
```

**As per the comment:**

You can wrap them in a span and apply white-space:nowrap to the span:

```
<a>This <span>way<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span></a>
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I don't think this will work for me because I need the words to wrap, and if you use nowrap in this way, then "way" will not wrap. That will break my design because the arrow will stick out of the div. I tried your suggestion in the codepen, but it didn't for me. (here is a fork: http://codepen.io/b-d-m-p/pen/XJJapR?editors=110 )

Comment: You want the icon go below line?

Comment: Right now, the icon does go to the next line, which is good, but I need the last word to go with it. I need the two of them to be a group but still wrap.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer also worked for me. I marked God is good answer as correct because he posted it a bit before, but I am grateful to you for your response. I'm a bit new to this site, so I hope that is the proper way to handle two correct answers. http://codepen.io/b-d-m-p/pen/OPPjWY